# How to get the correct id after INNER JOINING two tables which both have an id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I am developing a movies app and have a small issues that I need help to resolve.

I need to get the correct id for the url of an item in the database after completing an INNER JOIN.

When trying to target an id for an single item in the url, all items have the same id and information related to only 1 movie. I have tested it several different ways It appears the issue maybe with the query statement.
    How can I resolve this?

My environment is Running PHP 7.3, MySQL 5, Debian 9 and Apache 2.
    I can retrieve the correct information from the database after using this query in my list-movies.php:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movies INNER JOIN genres ON genres.id=movies.genre_id LIMIT 200";
```

Returns 200 movies with the title, summary, genre and year_released as
    expected.

edit.php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1";
```

HTML

```
<input type="number" readonly class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $result['id'] ?>">
```

Does not return expected results.

Comment: You should not use `SELECT *` if you want to be more precise about the columns you are reading

Comment: A few questions: 1) Can you show the results of the second question?  2) How are you executing the queries? 3) I dont see in your code where you use $results, where are you setting that?  Lastly, try not to SELECT *, instead, if you just need the id column, then just do SELECT id ...

Comment: @jdubu423 I used it. 
if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
    header('Location: list-movies.php');
    die();
} else {
    if(!filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
        header('Location: list-movies.php');
        die();
    } else {
        $id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1";
        $result = $db_connection->prepare($query);
        // Execute query with array
        $result->execute([
            'id' => $id
        ]);
        // Fetch result
        $result = $result->fetch();
    }
}
?>

Comment: @nico-hasse Yes got it. Thank you. Fixed it. The genre is connected to the genres table and represented by genre_id on the movies table. Do I need to make another query or sub-query to get the names of the genre? I am retrieving everything except the genre. Modified query: SELECT title, summary, release_date, min_duration, id FROM movies WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1